# Creating Setup from INNO Tool, Exe is not running?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, inno-setup, intellilock

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtgGK.png)Team,

Creating Setup file using INNO Tool and execute the setup file in windows 10 OS, and issue showing,

```
Unable to execute File:
c:\Program Files (X86)\Setup1\Test.exe
createprocess failed; code 740.
the requested operation requires elevation.
```

Please provide how to resolve this issue.
I have used sqlite database in my project.

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you can add the shellexec flag

```
Filename: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}; Flags: nowait postinstall shellexec skipifsilent
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the exe as administrator, see http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired

As a normal user you are not allowed to install this on your computer.